# Randomize Tumblr post order on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I have a tumblr with photos that I would like to appear in a random order on page load. I found a bit of code that does the trick, but the problem is that on page load, only the first few posts are loaded. The rest gets loaded when scrolling down, but this means that the script only applies to those first 10-12 posts. They get shuffled around every time, while the rest just loads in the order they were posted when scrolling down.

So with my very limited knowledge of coding, I'm guessing the other posts don't exist in the DOM yet and are created on the fly by some script while scrolling for performance reasons. But is there any way to force the page to load all the posts and then randomize the order from the start?

This is the script that I'm using right now

```
  var tiles = $(".photo");
  for(var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
  var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length -1) + 1;
  var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length -1) +1;
  tiles.eq(target).before(tiles.eq(target2));
  }
```

And here's the tumblr page: http://pieterwouters.tumblr.com/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffle() {
    var tiles = $(".photo:not('.shuffled')");
    for(var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
        tiles[i].addClass('shuffled')
        var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length -1) + 1;
        var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length -1) +1;
        tiles.eq(target).before(tiles.eq(target2));
    }
}

$(document).ready(shuffle);
```

This isn't exactly what you had in mind, but the trick here would be to shuffle when the page reload. I assume (badly) that tumblr executes a function on reloading. When that function is done, you could execute `shuffle()` again. I edited your inital code to add a class 'shuffled' so the function will not mix up existing shuffled content.